# How to retain values in yii after submit

Tags: php, yii

Doing a search form in PHP YII in which i need to enter 2 dates field Startdate and enddate, after submitting i will be fetching all the records from table where the contacteddate falls between these start and end date.

The problem is after submitting my textbox values are vanishing. How to retain after submitting?

Comment: are those properties in the safe list?

Comment: What you mean like safe list? you mean mentioning $model? If so, then no as these 2 fields are just for filters.

Comment: Try safe rule to that fields.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/

Answer (score 1):

You could use ajax to retrieve the results, instead of the default submit, that way your filter values will not change. The default submit behavior loads(navigates) to a url, hence your values disappear.

You can use [`CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxSubmitButton-detail) to easily implement this functionality. A sample:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
    'AjaxSearch', // label
    $url,// url that will search
    array('update'=>'#resultdiv'),// the element with id 'resultdiv' will be updated with the search result
    $htmlOptions 
);
```

Comment: if you are looking for a different kind of solution, you have to tell me, some feedback is always better than no feedback. after all i'm trying to help you!